# How can I test post-save, pre-save in the full system testing in Django with REST

Tags: python, django, testing, django-rest-framework

I have the application in `Django REST` as backend and `Angular as frontend`.

Suppose in This is my code

```
class ModelClass (models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.EmailField()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        #check if the row with this hash already exists.
        if not self.pk:
            self.hash = self.create_hash()
        self.my_stuff = 'something I want to save in that field'
        # call to some async task
        super(ModelClass, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

In my REST i have this view

```
class ModelListCreateView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    model = ModelClass
    serializer_class = ModelClassSerializer

    def pre_save(self, obj):
        obj.created_by = obj.updated_by = self.request.user.staff

    def post_save(self, obj, created=False):
            # add some other child objects of other model
```

I don't want to do unit testing. I want to do system testing so that I need to know if I post something to that view then

1. Pre-save thing should work
2. Record gets created
3. Save method of Model gets called with his stuff
4. After save method in REST gets called

Then I can assert all that stuff.

Can I test all that . I want to know which thing I need to have that sort of test rather than small unit tests

I am confused do I need to use `Django test` or `REST Test` or `selenium test` or `PyTEst` or `factory boy` because i want to know if things are actually getting in database

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking is some kind of a REST Client code that would then be able to run your tests and you would be able to verify if the call is successful or not. Django Rest Framework has the APIRestFactory helper class that will aid you in writing such tests. The documentation can be found [here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/testing/) and specifically look at the Example section. This would be part of your Django tests